# How do you create or modify a CMS Block without Deprecated Methods?

Tags: magento2.4, cms-block

How can I **create** or **modify** a **CMS Block** from a list according to that CMS Block if there is or not, in the same programming code **without depracted methods**?

---

`load()` & `save()` -> is the deprecated method:

```
$cmsBlock = $this->blockFactory->create()->load(...);
...
$cmsBlock->setData(...)->save();
...
$this->blockFactory->create()->setContent(...)->save();
```

Example:

```
if($blockId) {
    ... Update
}
else {
    ... Create
}
```

Us to imagine that the first exists:

```
$array = [
    [
        'identifier' => 'test_1',
        'title'      => 'Test 1',
        'content' => 'Test Content 1',
        'is_active' => 1,
        'store_id' => 0
    ],
    [
        'identifier' => 'test_2',
        'title'      => 'Test 2',
        'content' => 'Test Content 3',
        'is_active' => 1,
        'store_id' => 0
    ]
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Helper;

use Magento\Cms\Model\BlockFactory;
use Magento\Cms\Api\BlockRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;

/**
 * Class SetupCms
 *
 * @package YourBeef\Base\Helper
 */
class SetupCms extends AbstractHelper
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Cms\Model\BlockFactory
     */
    protected $blockFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Cms\Model\BlockRepository
     */
    protected $blockRepository;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder
     */
    protected $searchCriteriaBuilder;

    /**
     * @var \YourBeef\Base\Helper\Data
     */
    protected $helperData;

    /**
     * SetupCms constructor.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Cms\Model\BlockFactory $blockFactory
     * @param \Magento\Cms\Api\BlockRepositoryInterface $blockRepository
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder
     */
    public function __construct(
        BlockFactory $blockFactory,
        BlockRepositoryInterface $blockRepository,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
    ) {
        $this->blockFactory          = $blockFactory;
        $this->blockRepository       = $blockRepository;
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
    }

    /**
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    public function setCmsBlock(): void
    {
        $csvData = [
            [
                'identifier' => 'test_1',
                'title'      => 'Test 1',
                'content' => 'Test Content 1',
                'is_active' => 1,
                'store_id' => 0
            ],
            [
                'identifier' => 'test_2',
                'title'      => 'Test 2',
                'content' => 'Test Content 3',
                'is_active' => 1,
                'store_id' => 0
            ]
        ];
        $blockId = '';
        $storeId = 0;

        $cmsBlock = $this->blockFactory->create();

        foreach ($csvData as $cmsData) {
            $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter(
                'identifier',
                $cmsData['identifier']
            );

            $cmsBlockData = $this->blockRepository->getList(
                $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->create()
            )->getItems();

            if (count($cmsBlockData) > 0) {
                foreach ($cmsBlockData as $blockInfo) {
                    $blockId = (int)$blockInfo->getBlockId();
                }

                try {
                    $this->blockRepository->getById($blockId);
                } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    $this->_logger->error($e->getMessage());
                }

                $cmsData['block_id']        = $blockId;
                $cmsData['_first_store_id'] = $storeId;
                $cmsData['store_id']        = [$storeId];

                $cmsBlock->setData($cmsData);

                try {
                    // Update an existing CMS Block
                    $this->blockRepository->save($cmsBlock);
                } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    $this->_logger->error($e->getMessage());
                }
            } else {
                try {
                    // Create new CMS Block
                    $newCmsBlock = $this->blockFactory->create()->setData(
                        $cmsData
                    );
                    $this->blockRepository->save($newCmsBlock);
                } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    $this->_logger->error($e->getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use repository. E.g:

1. Load item by identifier:

```
    $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter(
        'identifier',
        'block-identifier'
    )->create();
    $blocks = $this->blockRepository->getList($searchCriteria);
```

2. Save

```
    try {
        $cmsBlock = [
            'title' => 'Test Title',
            'identifier' => 'block-identifier',
            'content' => 'block content',
            'is_active' => 1,
            'store_code' => 'en_us',
            'store_id' => [1]
        ];
        $block = $this->blockFactory->create();
        $block->setData($cmsBlock);
        $this->blockRepository->save($block);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {

    }
```

DI:

```
use Magento\Cms\Api\BlockRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Cms\Api\Data\BlockInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;

public function __construct(
        BlockInterfaceFactory $blockFactory,
        BlockRepositoryInterface $blockRepository,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder
    ) {
        $this->blockFactory = $blockFactory;
        $this->blockRepository = $blockRepository;
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
    }
```

**[Update]**

**Here is the correction of your answer:**
*Note:* I copied from your answer that you posted.

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Helper;

use Magento\Cms\Model\BlockFactory;
use Magento\Cms\Api\BlockRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;

/**
 * Class SetupCms
 *
 * @package YourBeef\Base\Helper
 */
class SetupCms extends AbstractHelper
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Cms\Model\BlockFactory
     */
    protected $blockFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Cms\Model\BlockRepository
     */
    protected $blockRepository;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder
     */
    protected $searchCriteriaBuilder;

    /**
     * @var \YourBeef\Base\Helper\Data
     */
    protected $helperData;

    /**
     * SetupCms constructor.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Cms\Model\BlockFactory $blockFactory
     * @param \Magento\Cms\Api\BlockRepositoryInterface $blockRepository
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder
     */
    public function __construct(
        BlockFactory $blockFactory,
        BlockRepositoryInterface $blockRepository,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
        ) {
        $this->blockFactory          = $blockFactory;
        $this->blockRepository       = $blockRepository;
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
    }

    /**
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    public function setCmsBlock(): void
    {
        $csvData = [
            [
                'identifier' => 'test_1',
                'title'      => 'Test 1',
                'content' => 'Test Content 1',
                'is_active' => 1,
                'store_id' => 0
            ],
            [
                'identifier' => 'test_2',
                'title'      => 'Test 2',
                'content' => 'Test Content 3',
                'is_active' => 1,
                'store_id' => 0
            ]
        ];
        $blockId = '';
        $storeId = 0;

        foreach ($csvData as $cmsData) {
            $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter(
                'identifier',
                $cmsData['identifier']
            );

            $cmsBlockData = $this->blockRepository->getList(
                $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->create()
            );

            if ($cmsBlockData->getTotalCount() > 0) {
                $cmsBlockItems = $cmsBlockData->getItems();
                $cmsBlock = array_shift($cmsBlockItems);
                $cmsData['_first_store_id'] = $storeId;
                $cmsData['store_id']        = [$storeId];
                $cmsBlock->setData($cmsData);
                try {
                    // Update an existing CMS Block
                    $this->blockRepository->save($cmsBlock);
                } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    $this->_logger->error($e->getMessage());
                }
            } else {
                try {
                    // Create new CMS Block
                    $newCmsBlock = $this->blockFactory->create()->setData(
                        $cmsData
                    );
                    $this->blockRepository->save($newCmsBlock);
                } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    $this->_logger->error($e->getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read my question: I will add a new explanation.

Comment: I have modified the answer that you posed as an anwer.